# Scrapy Change Items Order

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm scraping some data and exporting it to a json file, but i cant seem to set the order of the items. After doing some reading i found scrapy Items are wrappers of python dict and will return the item fields in an unpredicted order.

i have tried adding:

```
    def keys(self):
    return ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
```

now the output only consists of these 3 items but the order still remains unpredictable is there anyways i could set the order of these items ?

Comment: You can try yielding/returning `collections.OrderedDict` instances. Scrapy should understand them as items. I'm not sure that JSON exporting will respect key order but you can try (and report here for the rest of us)

Comment: it doesn't seem like it, json still changes the order of the items.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON, an object is defined thus:

```
An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.
```

See http://json.org.

Most implementations of JSON make no effort to preserve the order of an object's name/value pairs, since it is (by definition) not significant.

So in the end i switched the data format.